# What exactly lowers stealth score?

Tags: splinter-cell-double-agent

At the end of each mission, you receive a Stealth score, which can go up to 100%.

On Chaos theory, the score would get lower by (for example) killing enemies, but not knocking them out. However for Double Agent I can't find any information regarding this issue.

What exactly lowers this score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things that lowers the score include: Destroying any lights at all, which penalizes you with 2% off per light destroyed, same goes for locks destroyed also, 5% off the score per guard knocked out, or possibly killed, its the same for knocking out or killing civilians, in a nutshell, you are REQUIRED to ghost the entire level or else you wont get 100% stealth score, no touching anyone  at all. Always use the OCP to disable lights,dont get spotted or seen as an intruder, EVER. Which means, lasers, cameras, and guards absolutely cannot spot you once, if that happens, its an automatic -15% stealth score, but that is all i can find out.